# Import Product With Pipe Sign as configurable_variations

Tags: magento2, import, csv, special-character

I have an Product Attribute with following values : https://prnt.sc/u8JrDsg_noG0
now when I am trying to import with that : https://prnt.sc/jyArfXbh5Ezs
It gives me error : https://prnt.sc/ZoE3kIJhqB3a

It consider Pipe sign as a separator, so it gives me error in import process.

Is there any solution regarding this Issue ?

how can we import configurable product with configurable_variations values contain pipe sign ?

please help.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience of this issue, but my first thought would be to change the pipe in your spreadsheet to a numerical code: |

I know from experience that all those characters are allowed. You could still have raw pipes in your frontend view of the attribute as importers match against the admin view.

I use a 3rd party extension (Firebear import/export) for my files which gives me full control over what and how data is imported. I can use pipes, no problem. Highly recommend this:

https://firebearstudio.com/the-improved-import.html

(I have no affiliation with Firebear)

Comment: instead of pipe what should I have to use ?

Comment: The pipe looks to be just for style, you could use anything really. Hyphen would work well as a separator. :)